# C Threads creation issue

Tags: c, multithreading

Hi guys I'm having trouble with this code

```
int file_id;

void* wraper(void* p){  
    return (void)reader((int)p);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
srandom ((unsigned) time(NULL));
int i;
pthread_t tid[3];
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
     pthread_t * temp = malloc(sizeof(tid[i]));
     file_id=get_random(NB_FILES); 
     pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL,wraper,(void*)file_id); 
}
```

and the compiler is giving me this

```
reader-thread.c: In function ‘wraper’:
reader-thread.c:59:25: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
     return (void)reader((int)p);
                         ^
reader-thread.c:59:5: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     return (void)reader((int)p);
     ^
reader-thread.c: In function ‘main’:
reader-thread.c:70:46: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
          pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL,wraper,(void*)file_id); 
                                              ^
```

The objective is to create 3 threads and send them the file_id to the function reader, I can't see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: And how is `reader()` declared? And why are you returning a value you cast to `void`?!

Comment: reader is declared with reader(int file){...}

Answer (score 1):

1. Your compiler is correct, you shouldn't ignore this, on many architectures pointers and `int` don't have the same width. The correct type, if you really have to, is to use `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`.
2. Also casting the return of the function (that you didn't show us) to `(void)` makes no sense if you have to return a `void*`.
3. Casting the other way around from `int` to `void*` is almost as bad as 1.

In essence you shouldn't try to violate the call interface for thread functions. If you have to transmit data, pass a pointer to the data.

Also, please, when you post a question here, be sure that the error messages correspond to the code that you posted.

Comment: It does correspond, i just forgot to translate the funcion called leitor to reader